# Drools Planner: Planner not providing expected result based on Best Score

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I have tried posting on the user forum for Drools, but haven't been getting any responses (I am sure they are just busy), so I am hoping to attract a wider audience here.

I am very confused by the results I am getting as they seem to not be providing me with the "best score".  Here is some of the log output:

```
[construction steps] 
2013-03-13 08:00:08,305 [com....] INFO  Phase constructionHeuristic ended: step total (60), time spend (2222), best score (-200hard/-2780soft). 
[local search steps] 
2013-03-13 08:00:21,807 [com....] INFO  Phase localSearch ended: step total (42), time spend (15724), best score (0hard/-2495soft). 
2013-03-13 08:00:21,807 [com....] INFO  Solving ended: time spend (15724), best score (0hard/-2495soft), average calculate count per second (3748).
```

However, the results it gives me back contains a broken hard constraint (even though the log clearly states "Solving ended: time spend (15724), best score (0hard/-2495soft)") - it is giving me a result with score -200hard/-2495soft (which appears to be the hard score of the construction phase and the soft score of the local search phase).  Is this how it is supposed to be?  Did I miss something in the manual (I have read it, but I haven't digested it completely)?

Here is most of my solver config (just the potentially relevant portion):

```
<termination>
        <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
        <maximumSecondsSpend>60</maximumSecondsSpend>
        <scoreAttained>0hard/0soft</scoreAttained>
</termination>

<constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
    <constructionHeuristicPickEarlyType>FIRST_LAST_STEP_SCORE_EQUAL_OR_IMPROVING</constructionHeuristicPickEarlyType>  
</constructionHeuristic>

<localSearch>
        <termination>
                <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
                <maximumUnimprovedStepCount>20</maximumUnimprovedStepCount>
                <scoreAttained>0hard/0soft</scoreAttained>
        </termination>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
              <entitySelector>
                <entityFilterClass>com.....RequiredTypeEntityFilter</entityFilterClass>
              </entitySelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <swapMoveSelector>
              <entitySelector>
                <entityFilterClass>com.....RequiredTypeEntityFilter</entityFilterClass>
              </entitySelector>
            </swapMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <acceptor>
              <solutionTabuSize>1000</solutionTabuSize>
              <planningEntityTabuSize>7</planningEntityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
                <minimalAcceptedSelection>1000</minimalAcceptedSelection>
        </forager>
</localSearch>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Here is a little more information that might be helpful... As stated above, it says my best (Hard) score is 0, but the solution it gives me contains a Hard constraint violation.  I added some code to printout the constraints (using DroolsScoreDirector to get to the WorkingMemory and ultimately the ConstraintOccurrences)... this printout shows a hard constraint as well.

```
ConstraintType: NEGATIVE_HARD, RuleID: endLocationMustMatchStartLocation, Causes:...
```

Comment: Here's the [related forum post](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Using-EntitySelector-EntityFilterClass-td4022770.html). Looks like it didn't come through on the mailing list, due the Nabble hoops. We 're looking to remove those hoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your cloneSolution() method is corrupted (or the entity.clone() methods it calls). Double check those methods.

[In Drools Planner 6.0, you won't need to implement that cloning method.](http://blog.athico.com/2013/02/automatic-solution-cloning-in-planner.html)

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, I will try fixing my clone methods and report back on the result. I have seen several blog posts about 6.0 and look forward to its release (I will try beta once it is out).

Comment: Geoffrey, I did find a minor issue with my equals/hashCode in my Solution and the solutionEquals/solutionHashCode - I fixed it, but that still didn't solve the issue.  I could find nothing wrong with the clone on the planning entity nor the cloneSolution(). Can you think of anything else that might cause the issue?

Comment: Geoffrey, I added an edit above showing that the solution provided as the result contains a hard constraint violation... I am very confused why it doesn't seem to be giving me the "best" found solution based on the score.

Comment: @PaulP1975 It should give you the "best" solution found based on the score, so that's clearly an issue. I am pretty confident it's not in Planner (until proven otherwise). A few things to try: enable environmentMode FULL_ASSERT (see docs). If that doesn't crash it, turn it off again and debug BestSolutionRecaller.

Comment: in 5.5.x FULL_ASSERT is still known as TRACE

Comment: @Geoffrey... I agree, I doubt it is Planner... something is amiss, I am sure.  I will try those suggestions and report back.

Comment: meanwhile, read up on "incremental score calculation", <assertScoreDirectorFactory>, the mailing lists mail with "score corruption" and especially the causes parameter in IntConstraintOccurrence()'s source and the method insertLogical() in the droolsexpert manual

Comment: I still have an issue, but your direction has helped me isolate it to a specific rule.  I am getting score corruption and it is related to the parameters I am passing to the IntConstraintOccurrence object. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: after a LOT of thinking about my problem and looking at code/docs, I finally figured out the root cause of this issue.  It is the nature of the rule and the incremental calculator. The problem is that when a move is incrementally calculated, it only looks at the event being planned, but this rule would require a recalculation of the next event this resource was planned to.  In short, I need to implement my own IncrementalScoreCalc - I am looking into this now.

Comment: Geoffrey - looks like i might still need your help... here is the follow up issue with full explanation on the user forum: http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools-Planner-Need-help-with-IncrementalScoreCalculation-for-a-specific-move-td4022857.html - hopefully with your experience, this is trivial.  Thanks!

Comment: Needing to implement a custom IncrementalScoreCalculator shouldn't be needed (although that will solve your problem too of course). It could be a bug in drools 5.5.0.Final (you can use 5.5.1-SNAPSHOT to prove this) - soon 5.6.0.Final and 6.0.0.Beta1 will be released. It could be a bug in your causes parameter, due to the insertLogical complexity (which will be heavily reduced in 6.0.0.CR1 or 6.1)

Comment: Geoffrey, I haven't had a chance to try 5.5.1 yet, but a quick question... do you think if i included the "next" event in the causes parameters, would it recalculate the score for that event as well? I guess the real question is, does the "causes" parameter have any affect on the incremental "move" calculation?